# Selecting messages from user_id to user_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make really simple function user to be able to message to admin only and admin to answer on this message.

So far I've made table `message` with following columns

```
id | from_id | to_id | subject | message
```

In the controller I have this which should select all messages which are sent to current logged in user ( not sure if is correct )

```
public function index(){
        //$messages = Message::latest()->get();
    $currentUser = Auth::user()->id;
    $messages = Message::
        whereRaw('message.id = (select max(id) from `message` m2 where m2.to_id = '.$currentUser.')' )
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();        
    return view('test.index', compact('messages'));
}
```

Now I'm trying to make `viewMessage` function

In index blade this is the link to single message

```
{!! link_to('test/view/' . $message->from_id, $message->subject) !!}
```

My Route

```
Route::get('test/view/{id}', 'MessageController@messageView')->name('test.view');
```

And controller function

```
public function messageView($id) {

    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    $messages = $user->messages()->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
    return View::make('test.view', compact('messages'));
}
```

When I click on the button I got this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'message.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `message` where `message`.`user_id` = 4 and `message`.`user_id` is not null order by `created_at` asc)

In User model I've added relation to message like:

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

And in Message model

```
public function user(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

My question why in the query is looking for user_id when on my button I send from_id and how to fix this?

Comment: The error you getting is simple... it means on the message table there is no column name `user_id` check your table properly

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes, I get the error what is mean I just didn't get from where is came this user_id since I didn't add it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why in the query is looking for `user_id`

You need to [add foreign key and ID to the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) to fix the error, for example:

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'from_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I tough since I've added the FK's in tables it will use them.. But on second tough I should tell it what to look. Thank you